# Using Viewbag data with a HTMLHelper MVC3. - Cannot be dynamically dispatched

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, enums

I'm using the following function to turn my enums into a collection of `radiobuttons`

```
public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonForEnum<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression
)
{
```

However, this means I must use something like `html.RadioButtonForEnum(a => a.inputEnum)` to use it, - where `a` is my page model.

My issue arises when I want to do the following:
`html.RadioButtonForEnum(Viewbag.inputEnum)`

I get the following error:

```
CCS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<MyProject.Models.MyModel>' has no applicable method named 'RadioButtonForEnum' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.
```

I tried to apply a cast to it, but can't seem to get it to load if the enum is being passed in via a Viewbag -instead of a page model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Description

You can create a second method with you enumType as parameter instead of a expression.

#### Sample

```
public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonForEnum<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    TypeOfYourEnum value
)
```

#### More Information

- [ASP.NET MVC - Creating Custom HTML Helpers (C#)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 solutions that I can come up with:

Create a function that takes in the enum and not an expression:

```
public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonForEnum(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, MyEnumType enum)
{
  //Code to generate radio button here
}
```

Option 2 is to create a partial view (might be an over kill).